# Heroku: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/nav/_nav.html")

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I have completed Albert Pai’s  [AngularJS Tutorial:](https://thinkster.io/angular-rails/) *Learn to Build Modern Web Apps with Angular and Rails* following the instructions.  My app works locally when using WEBrick and Foreman. However after deploying the same app to Heroku, I ran into problems with the following AngularJS statement:

`<div ng-include="'nav/_nav.html'"></div>`

as at Heroku server the `_nav.html` partial view isn’t found. So I get the following error:

```
GET http://fathomless-sands-8666.herokuapp.com/nav/_nav.html 404 (Not Found)
```

Screenshot (I’m missing the navbar that allows login and registration, Device gem is used):

[image]

**application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>FlapperNews</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body ng-app="flapperNews">
    <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
    <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <div ng-include="'nav/_nav.html'"></div>
      <ui-view></ui-view>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**_nav.html**

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse pull-right" ng-controller="NavCtrl">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#/home">Home</a></li>
    <li ng-hide="signedIn()"><a href="#/login">Log In</a></li>
    <li ng-hide="signedIn()"><a href="#/register">Register</a></li>
    <li ng-show="signedIn()"><a href="#/">{{ user.username }}</a></li>
    <li ng-show="signedIn()"><a ng-click="logout()">Log Out</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Heroku log:**

```
2015-02-23T12:26:14.936469+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-71f8573cbf92d37602f8bd1449f54ed5.js" host=fathomless-sands-8666.herokuapp.com request_id=6695089f-3134-4397-81da-6832439bc1a4 fwd="212.149.201.185" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=10ms status=200 bytes=166290
2015-02-23T12:26:15.938797+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fathomless-sands-8666.herokuapp.com request_id=61831df5-456c-492b-a315-f0c13faa64cf fwd="212.149.201.185" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=143
2015-02-23T12:26:15.957956+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/nav/_nav.html" host=fathomless-sands-8666.herokuapp.com request_id=c40773c6-2f68-4533-b2a3-d9a1bad30ce7 fwd="212.149.201.185" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=59ms status=404 bytes=1531
2015-02-23T12:26:15.898369+00:00 app[web.1]: source=rack-timeout id=c40773c6-2f68-4533-b2a3-d9a1bad30ce7 wait=2ms timeout=20000ms state=ready
2015-02-23T12:26:15.935577+00:00 app[web.1]: source=rack-timeout id=61831df5-456c-492b-a315-f0c13faa64cf wait=2ms timeout=20000ms state=ready
2015-02-23T12:26:15.955427+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-02-23T12:26:15.955433+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/nav/_nav.html"):
2015-02-23T12:26:15.955437+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
```

**routes.rb**

```
FlapperNews::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  root to: 'application#angular'
  resources :posts, only: [:create, :index, :show] do
    resources :comments, only: [:show, :create] do
      member do
        put '/upvote' => 'comments#upvote'
      end
    end

    member do
      put '/upvote' => 'posts#upvote'
    end
  end
```

The code that was deployed to Heroku can be found at Github: https://github.com/jyrkim/flapper-news/blob/master/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb  I have also created Procfile and set the Puma gem as instructed at Heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4#specify-ruby-version-in-app The only thing that I didn’t specify in the Gemfile was the Ruby version. My Ubuntu uses Ruby version 2.1 and Heroku wants to use version 2.0 for my app. (Maybe that could cause the problem)

If someone has a clue what might be causing the problem at Heroku environment, then please let me know - Thanks.

Comment: I am doing the same tutorial, but having real difficulties with the ```angular-rails-templates``` and changing the ```templateURL: home/_home.html``` part. Did you have any issues with this? I am getting a message in the console that ```ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/home.html")```

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald Sorry, it's been a couple months since I made the tutorial, and I'm not quite sure did I have that particular problem (although, I might have had that one too, because at times the code samples in the tutorial weren't always covered 100%). Nevertheless, in the end I got the tutorial working after posting a couple questions on Stackoverflow. In relation to your problem,I'd check that  home/_home.html exists and routing is set for the previous file.  https://github.com/jyrkim/flapper-news/tree/master/app/assets/javascripts  (github has working code,but it's at complete stage)

Comment: thanks for the response. I actually figured it out through another SO post - it was an issue with sprockets. It was necessary to add the following line to the gemfile ```gem 'sprockets', '2.12.3'```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you ran an asset precompilation locally when you first deployed to Heroku (because you have older files in your `public/assets` directory) but have not run it again since making further changes to the site and re-deploying to Heroku.

This means that your pre-compiled JS is out of step with your `application.html.erb`. The JS your are serving from Heroku was compiled before `nav/_nav.html` was created and has not been updated since.

You can either run the asset pre-compilation again locally:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Or remove the `public/assets` directory, commit and redeploy so that Heroku performs the asset precompilation step as part of the deployment during slug compilation. Doing it this way means that you don't have to worry about running the rake task locally in future.

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline

Comment: I am getting this error I am getting this error ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/users/assets/application.js") do you have any idea how to solve it?