# Heroku: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I’m getting the following error at Heroku:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf)
```

when the server is trying to find Bootstrap’s [halflings images](http://getbootstrap.com/components/) from vendor assets:

When I run the app by using Puma and Foreman locally, then it’s working fine as those halfling images appear.

**Heroku log** is shown below:

```
2015-02-24T06:15:45.302830+00:00 app[web.1]: source=rack-timeout id=983308e6-3d6f-494b-b8e1-f37b39b14d42 wait=11ms timeout=20000ms service=2ms state=completed
2015-02-24T06:15:45.302416+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/lib/puma/server.rb:375:in `process_client'
2015-02-24T06:15:45.304253+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff" host=fathomless-sands-8666.herokuapp.comrequest_id=983308e6-3d6f-494b-b8e1-f37b39b14d42 fwd="212.149.201.185" dyno=web.1 connect=6ms service=6ms status=404 bytes=1531
2015-02-24T06:15:45.506425+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf" host=fathomless-sands-8666.herokuapp.comrequest_id=41275bad-2ed7-4cfd-89c5-d223b6063d62 fwd="212.149.201.185" dyno=web.1 connect=28ms service=37ms status=404 bytes=1531
2015-02-24T06:15:45.476848+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf" for 212.149.201.185 at 2015-02-24 06:15:45 +0000
2015-02-24T06:15:45.478340+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-02-24T06:15:45.478344+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf"):
2015-02-24T06:15:45.478347+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2015-02-24T06:15:45.471994+00:00 app[web.1]: source=rack-timeout id=41275bad-2ed7-4cfd-89c5-d223b6063d62 wait=33ms timeout=20000ms state=ready
2015-02-24T06:15:45.478349+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2015-02-24T06:15:45.478351+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2015-02-24T06:15:45.478353+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2015-02-24T06:15:45.478355+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
```

**application.css** file

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *= require bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

**.bower.json** file:

```
{
  "name": "bootstrap",
  "description": "The most popular front-end framework for developing responsive, mobile first projects on the web.",
  "version": "3.3.2",
  "keywords": [
    "css",
    "js",
    "less",
    "mobile-first",
    "responsive",
    "front-end",
    "framework",
    "web"
  ],
  "homepage": "http://getbootstrap.com",
  "main": [
    "less/bootstrap.less",
    "dist/css/bootstrap.css",
    "dist/js/bootstrap.js",
    "dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot",
    "dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg",
    "dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf",
    "dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff"
  ],
  "ignore": [
    "/.*",
    "_config.yml",
    "CNAME",
    "composer.json",
    "CONTRIBUTING.md",
    "docs",
    "js/tests",
    "test-infra"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": ">= 1.9.1"
  },
  "_release": "3.3.2",
  "_resolution": {
    "type": "version",
    "tag": "v3.3.2",
    "commit": "bcf7dd38b5ab180256e2e4fb5da0369551b3f082"
  },
  "_source": "git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git",
  "_target": "~3.3.2",
  "_originalSource": "bootstrap",
  "_direct": true
}
```

Those halflings can be found in two folders in my project: 
[vendor/assets/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts](https://github.com/jyrkim/flapper-news/tree/master/vendor/assets/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts)
[vendor/assets/bower_components/bootstrap/fonts](https://github.com/jyrkim/flapper-news/tree/master/vendor/assets/bower_components/bootstrap/fonts)

Apart from those halfling images, the app is working fine:

[image]

I have previously removed `public/assets` directory committed and redeployed to Heroku, which solved my older problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/28681947/2048391 thanks to Steve. The error message in the older issue (when the navbar didn’t appear) was quite similar to this one, so this issue might have something to do with assets as well.

If the issue sounds familiar to you, then please drop a line. Many thanks :-)

The code that was deployed to Heroku can be found at [GitHub](https://github.com/jyrkim/flapper-news/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a couple of issues here.

- The font assets aren't in a path known to the sprockets so they won't be served when asset compilation is on (i.e., production).
- Even if you fixed asset compilation, you are using a static version of bootstrap.css so the path to the font assets can't be set to match where rails will place them.

**Solution**:

1. Use the official bootstrap-sass bower package which will compile bootstrap with the proper font paths.

   Install bower-sass and remove vanilla bootstrap:

   ```
     bower uninstall bootstrap --save
   bower install bootstrap-sass --save
   ```
2. Move `application.css` to `application.css.scss`. Add the following lines after the mainfest section.

   ```
   $icon-font-path: "bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/";
   @import "bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap-sprockets";
   @import "bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
   ```

   You must also make sure to remove this line since the non-sass version of bootstrap was removed.

   ```
   *= require bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap
   ```
3. Add the vendored assets paths to application.rb so that rails can compile and serve them.

   You application.rb needs to be updated as well so that Rails knows where the assets live. Per the official bootstrap-sass documentation (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#c-bower):

   ```
   # Bower asset paths
   root.join('vendor', 'assets', 'bower_components').to_s.tap do |bower_path|
     config.sass.load_paths << bower_path
     config.assets.paths << bower_path
   end
   # Precompile Bootstrap fonts
   config.assets.precompile << %r(bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/[\w-]+\.(?:eot|svg|ttf|woff2?)$)
   # Minimum Sass number precision required by bootstrap-sass
   ::Sass::Script::Number.precision = [8, ::Sass::Script::Number.precision].max
   ```

This should resolve the problem and your glyphicons should be loading now.